# OpenMesh does not compile with min/max macros active

Tags: c++, c, macros

How can I deal with this error? I add NOMINMAX to the Preprocessor Definitions, but it just dose not work. So what is the solution?

the error is as follows.

```
ClCompile:
1>  tricall.c
1>  Detected min macro! OpenMesh does not compile with min/max macros active! Please add a define NOMINMAX to your compiler flags or add #undef min before including OpenMesh headers !
1>d:\programfiles\c_library\openmesh3.2\include\openmesh\core\system\config.h(72): fatal error C1189: #error :  min macro active
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
#ifdef min
#undef min
#endif
```

and similar for `max` before including the OpenMesh headers.

Some header not observing NOMINMAX is defining them.

If that breaks other code that relies on those macros, then use the more complicated

```
#ifdef min
#define foo min
#undef min
#endif
/*OpenMesh includes here*/
#ifdef foo
#define min foo
#undef foo
#endif
```

where `foo` is a symbol of your choosing.